# Randomized organic warp of adjacent polygons that preserves topology and fixed nodes

Tags: python, polygon, topology, hexagonal-grid

I'm looking for algoritms to modify a set of polygons to make them appear more organic. They still need to maintain their topology and furthermore some of the nodes might be fixed. Please see the example image below where the left hexagons needs be transformed to something like shown on the right.

[image]

Note the red fixed nodes, those are not to be moved.

I do know how to "randomize" a line, but not how to take topology and bounds into account as its likely the polygons will intersect if not careful. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I would love to know the names of good algorithms to use, or even better Python libraries or example code.